# How to check AnnotationInvocationHandler relationship with Annotation

Tags: java, reflection, proxy, annotations

I have an annotation defined as

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(FIELD)
@interface A {}
```

A class using this annotation

```
class C {
  @A String f;
}
```

However, at runtime it is wrapped by a `Proxy` with `AnnotationInvocationHandler`, e.g. `Field f = C.class.getField("f"); f.getDeclaredAnnotations()` returns an array of this `Proxy`. How can I check wether field `f` of class `C` is annotated with annotation `A` in this situation?

Note: `f.isAnnotationPresent(A.class)` returns `false`

Comment: Please give me your complete code. This never happen at least in OpenJDK.

Comment: Why do you think that the fact that it has been implemented by a proxy has any relevance? If `f.getDeclaredAnnotations()` returns an array containing a proxy implementing `A`, you know that the annotation is present. `isAnnotationPresent` does not do anything different.

Answer (score 0):

> f.isAnnotationPresent(A.class) returns false

This happens because your annotation `A` does not have [runtime retention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#RUNTIME) so the annotation is deleted at runtime (the default runtime retention is [`CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#CLASS)).

Try to modify your annotation in :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface A {
}
```

Then `f.isAnnotationPresent(A.class)` will return `true`.

Note : in some IDEs you have a warning when you call isAnnotationPresent if the annotation does not have runtime retention.
For example in Netbeans 8.1 you can see a message *`com.mypackage.A does not have runtime Retention, the result will always be false`*.

Comment: Thank you to mention it out. But my annotation in fact has Runtime retention policy.

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't knew that, you should modify your question to add all the annotations you have in your code.